# Is there a Spanish word for "typo"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English we use "typo" quite extensively to indicate a little error that was done due to inaccuracy while typing.

Like:

> He wrote my name as Jhon instead of John. It must have been a typo.

I wonder: is there any equivalent in Spanish for such word? I am thinking on "errata" but I don't know if this is still missing some context (because my English is not perfect so I may be losing part of its original meaning).

Comment: The Spanish word for that is **Errata** as stated on @jsantander answer. I think that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great!. Now we have 3 one-word translations. **Errata, pifia, gazapo**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No es un solo vocablo, pero la locución más frecuente es **error tipográfico**, la cual es un calco de la locución (*typographical error*) de que proviene el término *typo* en inglés.

Comment: También *error de tipeo*.

Comment: If the mistake appears in a printed text, you could also say _error de imprenta_.

Answer (score 11):

Errata is a correct translation for typo.

Looking up [typo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo):

> a mistake (such as a misspelled word) in typed or printed text

And looking up [errata](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=GVGTuLO2SDXX2XSXCDEt):

> 1. f. Equivocación material cometida en lo impreso o manuscrito.

The above defintion would imply any written error (both printed and non printed), with *error tipográfico* allowing to specify that it refers to a problem in the composition of a text. However, the common use is probably restricted to only printed text: For example a newspaper or a second edition of a publication might contain a *fe de erratas*: a list of the errors/typos in the previous edition.

Answer (score 4):

Sí, errata es una, la otra es **blunder** que significa **pifia**, o sea un pequeño errorcito en la escritura. (Aunque no necesariamente **pifia** implica error en la escritura, se suele usar para otras cosas que conlleven errores leves.)

Comment: La redacción es confusa: ¿"blunder" en castellano o en inglés? Nótese también que ["conllevar", no "conllevar a"](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/conllevar-no-conllevar-a-1368/)

Comment: Ah qué bien, no sabía lo de **conllevar**. Me refiero a que **pifia** es la otra forma para expresar la **errata**.

Comment: Mmm no acabo de estar de acuerdo. Para mí, "pifia" tiene una connotación más fuerte. De la DRAE, _Error, descuido, paso o dicho desacertado_

Comment: La RAE es muy estricta. En mi país **pifia** se usa bastante para connotar errores que son leves, no implica que sea algo prácticamente grave.

Answer (score 3):

In Costa Rica, it's popular to call this "un dedazo".

Answer (score 3):

Tal vez [**gazapo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J1qLm8A)

> Yerro que por inadvertencia deja escapar quien escribe o habla

Answer (score 2):

Una forma menos formal de llamarlo es "error de dedo".

> Escribió mi nombre Jhon en vez de John. Debió ser un error de dedo.

Answer (score -2):

"Error de ortografía" is the one I use always. Longer but safer.