# ¿Qué función tiene "de lluvia" en "hoy es un día de lluvia"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, categorías-gramaticales

"De lluvia" en "hoy es un día de lluvia" tiene una función similar a un adjetivo (es similar a decir "hoy es un día lluvioso"), pero ¿se puede decir que es un adjetivo? ¿O qué vendría a ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es, morfológicamente, una frase preposicional compuesta por preposición y sustantivo. Sintácticamente, es modificador indirecto, compuesto por nexo subordinante y término. Semánticamente tiene, como bien dices, valor adjetivo.

Comment: Al usar un nexo es un modificador indirecto, ¿no?

Comment: Si, perdón. Fue un error de tipeo. Ya lo corrijo. Gracias.

Comment: _Error de tipeo_, me gusta como [alternativa a _typo_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15261/1674)

Comment: Aquí en Argentina lo usamos todo el tiempo. Nunca decimos "tecleo" como en España.

Comment: @fedorqui en su momento fue mi comentario a la respuesta aceptada :)

Comment: @rsanchez ¡cierto! Ahora lo veo. Pues creo que sería bueno que alguien se animara a incluirlo como respuesta allí, para que sea más visible.